# Any reason why {% requirePermission 'editEntries:1' %} would stop working within the past week or so?

Tags: craft3, permissions

This worked fine last week when the site was in development:

```
{% requirePermission 'editEntries:1' %}
```

We made the site live a few days ago. I dont know if its related, but when I now go to pages with this on, I am getting

```
HTTP 403 – Forbidden – yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException
User is not permitted to perform this action
```

I have doubled checked all settings, they are still the same. The logged in user getting this message is in a group that is allowed to editEntries for section 1.

Thanks

Comment: Is your targeted section on the live website has the same ID (1) than on your dev environment(s) ?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you've recently updated to Craft 3.1, if you look in your `userpermissions` table you'll see that they're now lowercase and using UIDs rather than integer IDs, like this:

```
editentries:3bb69b06-3e65-4ae5-8d70-6c47c1a88fbe
```

The only place I can find anything like this documented is in the "Updating Plugins for Craft 3.1" guide

https://craftcms.com/guides/updating-plugins-for-craft-3-1#update-element-source-key-references

Comment: Oh wow that will be it then. Thanks a lot!. Googling wont return that page as there is no mention of "requirePermission". I didn't think such a major change would get slipped in like this without some warning as it broke our system and functionality.

Comment: Although I have no idea where to get the UID from in the admin. Craft seems to get harder and harder!

Comment: Yeah it's in the 3.1.0 changelog entry, and there's a migration in Craft for it: `m180518_173000_permissions_to_uid.php` but I can't find it documented anywhere else, and there is nowhere in the admin that displays a section's UID - I just read them from the database. I guess you can inspect the checkbox value in the permissions form.